# "Access is denied" to Admin when using Sysinternals Contig to defrag the $LogFile metadata file

Tags: performance, ntfs, windows-server-2008, defragment, sysinternals

I have folders with hundreds of thousands, to over a million files and subfolders in each parent.  I'm reading that the NTFS log file may be responsible for slow file creation and other actions.

How do I use [SysInternals Contig](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897428) to address this issue?

When I run `contig -v d:\$LogFile`

**What Doesn't work:**  (any combination of:)

- elevated (Run as admin) command prompt I get `access denied`.
- Safe mode.
- Windows 2008 Server, Windows 2012 R2 (to test for an API difference)

Research:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197162/ntfs-performance-and-large-volumes-of-files-and-directories 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115882/how-do-you-deal-with-lots-of-small-files

Comment: Read the instructions?  You might wish to use one of the various commercial products, many of them have a 30 day trial period.

Comment: @mdpc Not only did I read instructions on the page, but I also added research to ensure I'm using the correct tool.  What are you claiming that I'm missing?  Are you saying that 3rd parties will help me with this particular system file?  Which one?

Comment: The downvote should removed. This is a well researched question, and is asked in many places on the Internet, with no resolution